# Overload function for rvalues and lvalues

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading, rvalue

I am writing a library that uses shared pointers to build a complex structure of nodes. Since there can be cycles in the structure, and to avoid memory leakes, I decided to adopt the following strategy when building the structure: whenever I am passed a temporary object, I use a shared_ptr (to get the ownership); whenever I am passed a lvalue, I use a weak_ptr. According to my analysis and the way the library interface is designed, this should avoid cycles altogether.

However, I am having problems in using function overloading to understand when the parameter is a rvalue or a lvalue. Here is a very simplified example of the error I get:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class MyClass {
public:
    int a;
    // this class contains some pointers to the node structure
};

MyClass fun(MyClass &&x, MyClass &&y)
{
    // should produce an object that has ownership of the two others
}

MyClass fun(MyClass x, MyClass y)
{
    // should not take ownership, but just copy the pointer
}

int main()
{
    MyClass x, y;

    fun(x, y);
    fun(MyClass(), MyClass());
}
```

When compiling with g++ 4.8.2 I get the following error:

```
example.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
example.cpp:29:29: error: call of overloaded ‘fun(MyClass, MyClass)’ is ambiguous
     fun(MyClass(), MyClass());
                             ^
example.cpp:29:29: note: candidates are:
example.cpp:12:9: note: MyClass fun(MyClass&&, MyClass&&)
 MyClass fun(MyClass &&x, MyClass &&y)
         ^
example.cpp:18:9: note: MyClass fun(MyClass, MyClass)
 MyClass fun(MyClass x, MyClass y)
         ^
```

So, apparently the compiler cannot distinguish between the two calls. I thought the rvalue function has precedence over the pass-by-value function, but evidently I was wrong.

Also: I cannot declare the function to take const references, because I  want just to take ownership and then later modify the object at will, so the reference should not be constant.

Any ideas on how I may solve this problem?

Comment: I see, but if I define `fun(const MyClass &a, const MyClass &b)`, the compiler is happy. So, apparently in this second case the compiler can see the difference and give priority to one or the other.

Comment: Either have a single function taking by value and moving from it, or have two functions, one taking lvalue ref and copying and one taking rvalue ref and moving. Don't mix the two patterns.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change:

```
MyClass fun(MyClass x, MyClass y)
MyClass fun(MyClass&& x, MyClass&& y)
```

To:

```
MyClass fun(MyClass& x, MyClass& y)      // for lvalues
MyClass fun(MyClass&& x, MyClass&& y)    // for rvalues
```

In your original example, the temporary `MyClass` could bind to either a value or an rvalue reference (both are exact matches). But with the change, there's no ambiguity.

Comment: I tried this but, as I wrote in my question, I need later to modify the node, so I cannot pass a const reference (because the pointed object will be assigned to a non-const pointer)

Comment: @knulp You can safely remove the `const`.

Comment: Without const the example works fine. Thanks! @Barry, if you modify your answer to remove the const, I will accept and upvote.

Comment: Yeah not sure why I did that. Fixed.